# Represent SQL Entry As PHP Page

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

Can anyone here to solve my query.

1. I want to manage many PDFs on base of php and mysql. So, i make a script to show list of books with their author name and size from mysql and i were also categorize them.  ***Now i want to show a detailed page (where download link, author name, size, screenshots, description will show) of each book, this detailed page will open when someone click on book name only.***

**Script For List Of Books:**

```html
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysql";
$dbname = "db-gs";

// Create connection
$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$connect) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Selection of data
$sql = "SELECT id, bname, aname, size, cat, lang FROM books";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 echo "<table><tr><th>SNo:</th><th>Books</th><th>Size</th><th>Language</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["bname"]."</td><td>".$row["size"]."</td><td>".$row["lang"]."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Show us your code, describe where you got stuck and we will help you. But we will not write it for you from scratch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can suggest you on the conceptual level. For populating book details on each book's click can be achieved with the help of javascript or jquery easily.
Simply bind your book with the click event and asynchronously make a hit to database, prepare the json data with book details and then populate the page. You can read more about it on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

Or you can simply create a form with selection element for every book having an id(just keep the id in the hidden tag). On form submit, do your sql work at backend and prepare your html.

I would also suggest you to read on MVC framework and Angular JS.

Comment: OKay I Will Try It

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it worked for you. Thanx